# Is there any way to automatic change package.json's latest or asterisk(*) mark to specific version?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, package.json

I use npm [Node Packaged Modules](http://www.npmjs.com) to manage project library,
But I notice unconditional **latest** update version make me hell.
(Too many unmet dependencies error..)

So I try to find to change all latest version to my local current version. I find the --save flag make some libraries specific version, but not all. Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Will [--save-exact](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) help?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with info on `npm shrinkwrap` that should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies), you can use a "semver" string to specify how to match the specific version, or how that version number can change, to control your dependencies as follows:

```
version Must match version exactly
>version Must be greater than version
>=version etc
<version
<=version
~version "Approximately equivalent to version" See semver(7)
^version "Compatible with version" See semver(7)
1.2.x 1.2.0, 1.2.1, etc., but not 1.3.0
```

It's also worth reading the [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/blob/master/README.md) documentation which defines in more detail how to specify and control the versions of your dependencies that match.

The other command to investigate is `npm shrinkwrap` - this prepares a npm-shrinkwrap.json file (which will be used by `npm install` instead of package.json, if present) which has the specific versions recorded in it, meaning future `npm install`'s should always give those specific versions. See the [NPM documentation for shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) for further information.

Comment: @SangJaeLee no problems - if you're happy that it answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Ok, have a nice day!!,